# Why are the textures being distorted in final render vs in viewport

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

So I have two objects:

1. A Uv Unwrapped Object (Arrow Buttons) with the arrow texture.
2. A duplicate of the same object, but fattened (alt+s edit mode) and applied a
   transmission texture with clearcoat.

[image: Viewport Image]
Viewport Render

In the viewport everything is fine and dandy, all the arrows are appearing visible and positive, but as soon as I try to render this same frame out:
[image]

This is what I get.

I have tried:

1. Changing of HDRIs
2. Increasing Light Samples
3. Messing with the plastic material on top to see if that's an issue
4. Messed with noise settings in render to see if that's causing it.

But to conclude, nothing's been helping me and I want to just complete this part to finish my animation.

Really Appreciate your help in advance!

[image]

Comment: modifiers settings that are not the same in viewport and render, maybe... or some objects that are hidden in viewport but not in render

Comment: @lemon as far as the buttons are concerned there are no extra modifiers applied to them and there are no objects hidden or in between them

Comment: so Z fighting, as the two surfaces are very close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object "White Controller Plastic" has a child object "controller_white.012" which is hidden in the viewport, but not disabled in render, this interferes with the controller button:

[image: hidden object]

Comment: I have been stressing so much for this lol this is gold, 
How would you find out in future in case you have this similar case, I was so busy in animation that this completely caught me off guard

Comment: @AtharvaDeodhar Depending on how many objects, I sometimes just look for them, or with all unselected I press `Alt`+`H` to unhide everything. By default settings, when the objects get unhidden they are selected. If there is an object where there should not be one like where the buttons are, I select specifically this, go to the _Outliner_, press `Numpad .` and the object gets exposed. Now that I know where it is I undo until the objects are hidden again (because some should stay hidden), then I deal with issue. Objects in disabled collections are not revealed, so they are no problem.